# How to remove all permissions from a user in Django Guardian?

Tags: django, django-guardian

I'm trying to reset my user permissions to assign new objects permissions to my user. how to achieve that ?

**For Example**:

having 3 chained models `School` & `Grade` & `StudentRecord`

**Models.py**:

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"),max_length=50)
    # other fields ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Grade(models.Model):
    code_name = models.CharField(_("Name"),max_length=50)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=False,related_name='grades')
    # other fields ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.code_name

class StudentRecord(models.Model):
    code_name = models.CharField(_("Name"),max_length=50)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=False,related_name='grades')
    grade = models.ForeignKey(Grade,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=False,related_name="student_records")
    # other fields ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.code_name
```

When I give a `User` as a **Manager** the *perms* (*add*,*change*,*view*,*delete*) for all objects of models which belong to specific school that `User` manage. **If** I need to change the *Manager* (`User`). I need to reset all permissions and reassign for all related objects of this specific school.

**How** To Acheive This Approach? any support will be appreciated.

Comment: cannot we achieve this by determining user type?

Comment: yup we can for sure, but for clean code sake I prefer to use `user type` or `user role` for viewing pages and url checks. and user permissions for object handling or data access

Comment: Yeah I do on same as your approach I use enum class to determine user type and have rest of validation Based on user type given the model instance